# How would I create a negate binary function in racket

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I am confused on how to approach this function

The function negate-binary consumes a list of natural numbers, alist, and produces
a list containing the ones complement of the numbers in the list that are valid binary numbers
(i.e. numbers that only contain 0s and 1s).

The ones’ complement numbers in the produced list must
be in the same relative order as the original binary numbers appear in alist.

Assume none of the numbers have leading 0s; in other words, alist will not contain any numbers like 0001

- number->string and string->number may be helpful *

```
(negate-binary (list 1000 101010 123 111)) ⇒ (list 111 10101 0)
(negate-binary (list 95 137 401)) ⇒ empty
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#lang racket

; 1String is a String of length 1.

; [List-of Number] -> [List-of Number]
(define (negate-binary lon)
  (map ones-complement (filter is-binary? lon)))

; Number -> Boolean
; is `num` a binary number?
(define (is-binary? num)  
  (andmap is-binary-1string? (num->1string-list num)))

; Number -> [List-of 1String]
; number to a list of 1strings
(define (num->1string-list num)
  (explode (number->string num)))

; String -> [List-of 1String]
; convert a string to a list of 1strings
(define (explode str)
  (map string (string->list str)))

; 1String -> Boolean
; is 1string a binary 1string?
(define (is-binary-1string? 1string)
  (or (string=? 1string "0") (string=? 1string "1")))

; Number -> Number
; one's complement of a number
(define (ones-complement num)
  (str-list->number (flip-bits (num->1string-list num))))

; [List-of 1String] -> [List-of 1String]
; "0" to "1" and "1" to "0" in list of 1strings
(define (flip-bits lo1s)
  (map flip-bit lo1s))

; 1String -> 1String
; convert "0" to "1" and "1" to "0"
(define (flip-bit 1string)
  (if (string=? 1string "0") "1" "0"))

; [List-of 1String] -> Number
; convert the list of 1strings to a number
(define (str-list->number lo1s)
  (string->number (apply string-append lo1s)))


(module+ test
  (require rackunit)
  (check-equal? (negate-binary (list 1000 101010 123 111)) (list 111 10101 0))
  (check-equal? (negate-binary (list 95 137 401)) empty))
```

**Edit**: removed all higher-order list abstractions like `map`, `andmap`, `filter` and `apply`.

```
#lang racket

; 1String is a String of length 1.

; [List-of Number] -> [List-of Number]
(define (negate-binary lon)
  (ones-complement* (binary-only lon)))

; [List-of Number] -> [List-of Number]
; only keep the binary numbers
(define (binary-only lon)
  (cond
    [(empty? lon) '()]
    [else (if (is-binary? (first lon))
              (cons (first lon) (binary-only (rest lon)))
              (binary-only (rest lon)))]))

; [List-of Number] -> [List-of Number]
; one's complement for all numbers in lon
(define (ones-complement* lon)
  (cond
    [(empty? lon) '()]
    [else (cons (ones-complement (first lon))
                (ones-complement* (rest lon)))]))

; Number -> Boolean
; is `num` a binary number?
(define (is-binary? num)  
  (all-binary-1strings? (num->1string-list num)))

; [List-of 1String] -> Boolean
; are all 1strings in lo1s binary?
(define (all-binary-1strings? lo1s)
  (cond
    [(empty? lo1s) #true]
    [else (and (is-binary-1string? (first lo1s))
               (all-binary-1strings? (rest lo1s)))]))

; Number -> [List-of 1String]
; number to a list of 1strings
(define (num->1string-list num)
  (explode (number->string num)))

; String -> [List-of 1String]
; convert a string to a list of 1strings
(define (explode str)
  (charlist->string-list (string->list str)))

; [List-of Char] -> [List-of 1String]
; convert a list of characters to a list of 1strings
(define (charlist->string-list charlist)
  (cond
    [(empty? charlist) '()]
    [else (cons (string (first charlist))
                (charlist->string-list (rest charlist)))]))

; 1String -> Boolean
; is 1string a binary 1string?
(define (is-binary-1string? 1string)
  (or (string=? 1string "0") (string=? 1string "1")))

; Number -> Number
; one's complement of a number
(define (ones-complement num)
  (str-list->number (flip-bits (num->1string-list num))))

; [List-of 1String] -> [List-of 1String]
; "0" to "1" and "1" to "0" in list of 1strings
(define (flip-bits lo1s)
  (flip-all-bits lo1s))

; [List-of 1String] -> [List-of 1String]
; flip bits of all 1strings in lo1s
(define (flip-all-bits lo1s)
  (cond
    [(empty? lo1s) '()]
    [else (cons (flip-bit (first lo1s))
                (flip-all-bits (rest lo1s)))]))

; 1String -> 1String
; convert "0" to "1" and "1" to "0"
(define (flip-bit 1string)
  (if (string=? 1string "0") "1" "0"))

; [List-of 1String] -> Number
; convert the list of 1strings to a number
(define (str-list->number lo1s)
  (string->number (join-all lo1s)))

; [List-of 1String] -> String
; join all 1strings in lo1s into a single string
(define (join-all lo1s)
  (cond
    [(empty? lo1s) ""]
    [else (string-append (first lo1s)
                         (join-all (rest lo1s)))]))


(module+ test
  (require rackunit)
  (check-equal? (negate-binary (list 1000 101010 123 111)) (list 111 10101 0))
  (check-equal? (negate-binary (list 95 137 401)) empty))
```

Comment: Hey Atharva very much appreciated. However, we are not allowed to use abstract functions like map etc. Just basic functions

Comment: Hi loren, I have updated the answer to remove all the non-basic functions.

Comment: Hello thank you Atharva. Just a quick question, is there any way I can simplify all this. I believe there are a lot of helper functions. Also we cannot use if statements just cond.

Comment: converting ifs to conds is straightforward, you can simplify further by inlining some functions like `flip-bits`, `explode`, `str-list->number`

Comment: When i try to simplify the ifs to conds, it gives me an error.